# Printing onThermal printer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, printing

I am using Codeigniter .I want to print billing details of  customers on a web using thermal printer.how can I print billing details using php/javascript/jquery .Is there any simulator to test this?.
Any one please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot using strictly ci. You can either print the html using javascript still need user permission) or search for third party printing software that provides an user api (only if the printer is local, the same place as the script). I used once but I cannot remember the apps name.

I made a text file then with exec accesed the 3rd party software telling to print the text file...

Hope this helps.

Comment: You have tried $(document).print(); or this.print();?